# gap between UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to place small gap between `UITableViewCell`, is there way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `UITableView` you have 2 properties : `separatorStyle` and `separatorColor`, but maybe it is not enough for you.

Then you need to implement them by yourself :
If your TableView has for example 12 cells you can use 12*2-1 cells (-1 because we don't need separator for the first cell) where odd number (starting from 0) will be your custom separator, with custom height, color or images like you would like but you have to do that by yourself.

```
0 => cell
1 => Separator
2 => cell
3 => Separator
4 => cell
...
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: What would this separator be and how would you set it? Would it be a custom cell?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a bigger height for the cell :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    return realCellHeight + margin;
}
```

realCellHeight is the height value of your custom UITableViewCell in your XIB.

Comment: It is not the answer for they question